# Improve guidance for users who are in danger of being quality-banned

Tags: feature-request, support, post-ban

I had posted my first question.
I got negative feedback and deleted it.

#### Request No. 1

User should be shown a pop-up message while deleting a post:

> "This would be taken into account. So it is better to improve your question and convince people rather than deleting".

If I had gotten this I could surely have preferred this but I was happy after deleting that I had deleted my negative reputation.

**I had deleted my own post thrice and got banned from asking more questions. But later I learned that it was being taken into account.

On my third time post I was told by some good soul that I was wrong with my formatting, causing negative feedback**

#### Request No. 2

During the posting of answers, the user should be warned/forced to properly format the contents. It should be asked as requirement while posting question if he/she does not do it him/herself.

I came to know the reason for getting negative feedback, when some good soul edited my post and just formatted it voluntarily and then I got positive voting rather than negative.

It was definitely my fault to not read all details from everywhere before posting a question. But I could have been guided better as well.

My ban was lifted (my luck/effort) but I think new users can be guided a bit better to avoid getting banned.

Comment: why are you banned?

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka I think due to deleting my own post twice or may be thrice.

Comment: So this is a feature-request rather than support? With regards to lifting your ban, only you can do so. There is nothing we can do about that really.

Comment: Thanks @Bart. Do you know pleases how can it be done? or who can do it for me?

Comment: If you knew that you were getting those downvotes because of badly formatted questions, why did you keep posting badly formatted questions?

Comment: Only you. Follow [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). Read it and read the first answer. It will tell you why you might have been banned and what you can do. Long story short, positively contribute where you still can, gaining some rep in the process. And improve the questions you have asked as much as possible. As to the deleted questions, any chance you can whip them into a good enough shape for them to be undeleted? Improve them. (Don't transform them into a different question though).

Comment: @Juhana. I came to know that, when some good soul edited my post and just formatted it voluntarily and then I got positive voting rather than negative.

Comment: Thanks @Bart. I have followed that link. Thanks for the summary. My question is too old now and getting no more responses. I have got answer for that now by studying many hours. There is not told anything else like that much rep from answering can lift your ban or that much people have to favor you to lift that ban. I could not read something like this. Do you think its told?

Comment: `It should be suggested while posting question (code related questions).` It does, not sure why it was not triggered for your question. But might have something to do with the formatting (bold) you applied to the code. `But I could have been guided better as well.` There is a FAQ button in the menu, there's a big "How to ask correctly" box when asking questions, there's a question mark in the formatting-toolbar...

Comment: Do people even read the FAQs? They may not even aware that they will get a badge for reading it.

Comment: Could you perhaps turn this into a feature request only? For your "please lift my ban" question, the post I linked you to will suffice. And that question is most often closed as a duplicate anyway. Right now it distracts from your feature request, which might perhaps have some merit.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Probably not, but what are we supposed to do about that?

Comment: Thanks for the complements @WaffelizedBobby sir.
I stated that "It was definitely my fault to not read all details from everywhere before posting question". I think you can not post code in answers normally without formatting it (I had to forcefully format my first answer (I remember). Unfortunately I could not realize/remember it while posting question and I was not forced/asked that time. I can not post questions due to be banned otherwise i could reconfirm that weather the site ask for formatting or not, I think not at the time of question but yes while answering

Comment: See also: ["Warn users before their account is suspended"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123026/warn-users-before-their-account-is-suspended). I agree that we need a better warning system in place for users getting close to an automated question or answer ban, but I also recognize that most people facing this wouldn't even read those warnings. Still, it would be nice to have for the few who would.

Comment: @nhahtdh - no, they do not.  Is there a website anywhere in existence where people show up and say, "ok, lemme find the instruction manual so I know what to do"

Comment: @Brad - if you put the warning right in front of their face, and say "Knock this sh*t out or you'll be facing suspension", then yeah, I think a lot more people would read it.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Agree. I didn't read it. You can see how I get by since I'm only answering question on SO. (I learn the rest from reading comment and look at how people do it).

Comment: @AdamRackis Great Comment :)

Comment: Sir @Juhana. Please remove your comment, if you think you can do, as I have now answered to your question in bold (in my question). I am being afraid of negative feedback again as your comment is being most liked :) What is the reason (which i am unable t understand) of liking of your comment even after its being answered in edited question? Is my answer invalid?

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. Your feedback has helped me out as needed.
I can ask questions now. Thanks to stack-overflow. Thanks for the votes and special thanks for the guidance. Should I tell this in my question? or there is a better way? or i should not do it @AdamRackis

Comment: Don't do anything - just ask clear, on-topic questions, and the rest will take case of itself :)

Comment: Thanks Adam Rackis. Sorry agin being unclear. In my last comment I was talking about the publishment of my Thanks "for feedback of you people for this post"
I wanted to pay thanks better way as its not much visible in comments.

Answer (score -3):

I can see "Bans" the only reason for a programmer to give up using SO. Bans must be practiced as they are need of forum but in little bettr way. Following all should be done gradually, **Only if getting new users and keeping them alive in community is suitable for StackOverflow**.

1. I was told after getting banned but I think users should be first informed and enforced to get instructions why you are going towards Ban and how can you avoid, before getting banned and then warned and then banned (if they do not follow any given instructions). User should be told that you have to follow instructions to survive.
2. New users to be warned on deleting a downvoted-post the consequence of deleting post.
3. No one should be allowed to down-vote, First answer and at least first two questions of any new user until they comment on the post and such comments should be separate from others and labelled as suggestions. So the user would be able to ping them back after improving the question according to suggestions

Following paragraph is taken from the accepted answer of a similar question
[How can you know that you are quite close to losing your account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-can-you-know-that-you-are-quite-close-to-losing-your-account)

I'd like to see a red zone where, if you stray over, the account is shut off and a yellow zone, where you are made aware that there's a problem and that if you ask too many more questions without moving to safety your account will be shut off.
Once you're in the yellow zone you should get a nice banner when the question asking interface is shown indicating why you are in the yellow zone and some specific direction on how to get back to safety.

Comment: There is plenty of information about how to post properly on the site in the FAQ's. People who are getting question/answer banned are *not reading that information in the first place*. Why, oh-why, do you think they will read *anything else* that is placed before them?

Comment: Anyone (with the rep to do so) should be allowed to downvote *anything, at any time*, without so much as saying hi. You don't get question-banned by someone downvoting you; you get banned by having the community as a whole *consistently* downvote you, or by stuff getting consistently deleted (even if by you). That hardly ever happens if your posts are on topic and show evidence of a decent amount of effort on your part -- both in doing a bit of research on your own, and by posting a clear and legible question -- so others don't have to waste their time doing stuff you should have already done.