# Notify users when they are approaching the threshold of getting banned (or when they do something bad)

Tags: feature-request, notifications, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you know that you are quite close to losing your account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-can-you-know-that-you-are-quite-close-to-losing-your-account)
>   [Warn users before their account is suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123026/warn-users-before-their-account-is-suspended)

I just found out that I was banned from answering questions today. I contacted the team and luckily I received an answer quite fast (the same day, thanks btw), which I wasn't expecting. It seems like the problem was that I posted comments as answers, so my bad. To be honest I started using this site when google started sending me here more and more, and at first at least, I didn't pay much attention to all of the features, so to speak.

The problem is that I wasn't at all aware of the issue until I got banned. There was no notification, no warning, nothing. In hindsight, I should have read the FAQ and I should have took the time to learn how the site works. But still, I presume this kind of thing happens quite often. And it's unpleasant to both the person getting banned, and the person dealing with the complaining email.

So my suggestion would be to send a notification when someone is getting close to being banned, possibly with a link to the documentation about how to avoid it. Now if my situation is unique it's not worth the trouble, but as I said, I presume it's not. If you guys feel that such a thing might help people figure out the system, another option is to send notifications when someone is doing something that might get them banned. For example if your answers are getting deleted or if you get more than a certain number of vote downs. I realize these are obvious things to avoid, but from my personal experience I can tell you people might not realize that it's happening, or how serious it is.

Comment: There are "mod messages" but the mods use them sparingly, and many times the banning is done automatically without any mod intervention.

Comment: I think there is a duplicate of this... Found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123026/warn-users-before-their-account-is-suspended and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-can-you-know-that-you-are-quite-close-to-losing-your-account

Comment: @nhahtdh i think there might be one too... I just can't find it. [update: ahhhh thanks ^_^]

Comment: Hold on - are you saying that you got *banned for posting comments as answers?*  I doubt that would be grounds for a ban...

Comment: @Lix: I think it would, since the "answer" will be deleted.

Comment: @Lix, answers as comments. I edited and fixed the question. Thanks for pointing it out, I'm somewhat dyslexic so it happens from time to time that I switch words like that.

Comment: Answers as comments? Now it makes absolutely no sense. :/ That implies you're posting a comment that should be an answer... which is not something you'd ever get banned for.

Comment: @ani - not having enough rep to post comments so **placing the content of a comment in an answer...**

Comment: Answers as comment or comment as answer? It doesn't make sense after the edit. Post answer as comment is OK, but comment as answer is no good.

Comment: I think you should have 20 rep or own the Analytical badge before being able to answer a question.

Comment: @ChrisGerken: I don't remember there being that requirement. You can even answer the question anonymously.

Comment: ok now I'm confused...  What was that last edit?

Comment: @Lix seems I'm confused also. Here's what the email said:

It seems like a lot of your content was removed because you were using the "answers" function to ask further questions.

Comment: yes... that means that you posted an answer that was only seeking more information... usually comments are used for that but in your case you didn't have the required 50rep to post comments...

Comment: @sorin7486 - If it helps to clear things up, you had posted three follow-on questions as answers. Because these weren't really answers, they were flagged by the community and deleted by moderators. Once a certain number of these happen, the safeguards kick in and you are banned from providing further answers. Unfortunately, a warning would not have helped in this case, since all three were flagged and deleted in the span of a few minutes.

Comment: @BradLarson thank you for the explanation. Still it wouldn't be a bad idea to get an email when your content gets flagged.