# Can't delete my own question, and mod flags keep getting declined

Tags: support, flags, moderation, self-delete

I've tried multiple times to delete my question: [Storing data locally - doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798329/storing-data-locally-doesnt-work)

When I try to delete it I get the error:

[image: Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.]

I followed the error's instructions and flagged the post, but it was declined because "You can delete it yourself":

[image: First flag]

Apparently the mods can't see the same error I can, so I screenshotted it and flagged the post again. This time it was declined because "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it":

[image: 2nd flag]

What is going on? I'm trying to delete a useless question, and the community finally closed it (afterwards) for the same reason. It's kind of unfair to lose 20% of my allotted flags on this.

Comment: Why do you want it deleted so bad anyway?

Comment: Can't ask any qustion anymore has not enough of my question got upvoted since i'm posting in a tag which has not many users

Comment: @Fawar Then you absolutely *do not* want the question deleted.  Deleted question strongly contribute towards being question banned, more so than most any other factors.  It will become *much* harder to dig yourself out of the hole that you're in if this question is deleted.

Comment: @Fawar: Deleting questions will make the problem worse

Comment: @WesleyMurch Well, given the answer to Juergend's question, it's actually *quite* relevant as deleting it will actually be counter productive for the OP, given his motivation for deletion.  I'm glad he asked.

Comment: @Servy once again, it's not the point. Motivation has no bearing on site functionality.

Comment: So deleting my post make me unable to post has im trying to remove what is considered bad for the community?

I guess that with about 10-15 post deleted, this account is done for good -_-'

Comment: @WesleyMurch: So? The point here is to help users and/or make them understand the situation. Extra info that helps us help them is always better.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It wasn't an answer.  He wasn't saying that this meta question isn't valid, he was simply asking a related question and, given the answer, it's now clear that the OP should not delete their question.  That's helpful.  Why are you so set against this helpful question being asked?

Comment: @Servy You're right, it's just me being bitter. It just seems so typical for people to attempt to invalidate a question with some short quip like that. I answered an SO question the other day where some 30K user asked the OP *"Why do you need a bottom margin on that div anyways??!"*. It just drives me nuts, I'm gonna take a break from this place again.

Comment: Let's stop discouraging self-deletes of bad questions. :/

Comment: @WesleyMurch Asking someone why they need to do X doesn't mean that they shouldn't be doing X, it just means that they need more context to help solve the problem.  It's a way of addressing the XY problem.  If you know what the true problem is rather than the solution the OP thinks will work you may find a better/easier/quicker solution that solves the *true* problem.  He wasn't saying, "You shouldn't delete the question."  However, once finding out the true motivation, it became clear that deleting the question doesn't actually help him, it hurts him, so telling him not to delete helps.

Comment: @Servy Yeah I get it, nevermind.

Comment: @user414076 Why?  I'm more inclined to just not allow it at all, or make it much harder to do, so that people don't q-ban themselves without realizing it.  Keep in mind what the purpose of the site is; it's to create a repository of programming knowledge for the world at large.  People asking questions, getting their problem solved, and then deleting right away *harms the site's primary goal*.

Comment: @Servy, if the question is bad, we don't want it. If the user gets question-banned for deleting it, I have no qualms with that. (Personally, I think if the content is *bad*, there should be no additional punitive consideration for deleting it. Let the negative score be enough. But since I don't know the algorithm, I don't know precisely how it's weighted if at all.)

Comment: @user414076 negative score gets reimbursed when the question is deleted, so how is it punitive?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, punitive as in when people say "deleting increases the chance of being question banned." (Grain of salt, given that none of us know the algorithm.) Rep changes are a different discussion.

Comment: @user414076 Although there are _a lot_ of comments on MSO that imply deleting questions somehow increases the chance of being q-banned, we simply don't know that. What we do know, however, is that deleting questions makes it harder to get out of the q-ban: you can't improve something you can't find. Also, a lot of newer users are unaware that deletions are soft (and that's understandable). We make a point of mentioning that deletions count as they might think that once they've deleted a question it's gone for good, and they need not worry about it anymore.

Comment: @Servy Something users can see by themselves that their questions are useless to others and since the goal is to create a repository of knowledge they don't want to add something which has no value to it.

Comment: @Fawar Then they shouldn't be asking questions like that to begin with.  You're to the point where you're posting questions with the intent of deleting them as soon as you get an answer, which means you're knowingly draining resources from the community without giving back at all.  It should not be surprising that such behavior would not be allowed to continue indefinitely.

Comment: @Yannis Developers with knowledge of the algorithm have explicitly stated that deleted questions contribute to being q-banned, so we do actually *know* that they contribute, just not to exactly what degree.

Comment: @Yannis, I agree, we don't know that (or to what degree, Servy mnetions), but my larger point is we should not discourage deletes of *bad* content. *If* that's part of the question ban algorithm, then I would recommend changing it to only punish deletions of *neutral-to-good* content. (...And then question ban everybody anyway.)

Comment: There is a very real sense in which what Stack Overflow is not letting you do is delete *other people's* content if there is any sign that it might be good content. Because that is what deleting a question with answers would do: scrap the work that other people have voluntarily done to help you.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I know. But "strongly" and "more so than most any other factors" in your [earlier comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183353/stackoverflow-doesnt-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-question#comment559474_183353) is pure speculation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears you're question banned. You have 17 deleted questions out of 30  questions, most of which you've deleted yourself.

Deleted content counts towards a post ban.  If that content has no votes or negative votes, that's going to hurt you.

Deleted content also cannot be undeleted without moderator attention (if deleted by a moderator), and since you lose sight of its URL when you delete it, you also can't get back to it easily.

Why do you keep deleting your content?  If the answer is 'because you found your answer', it's going to come to a point where you won't be able to post any more questions.

Your best bet is to:

- Improve your existing content so it gets upvotes
- Stop deleting content
- Don't ask questions when you don't know enough to know whether or not you should ask them.  In some cases, it seems like you asked the question and then realized the answer to the problem.

Here are links to your deleted posts. If you want to be unbanned, please try to improve them and flag them for undeletion (or undelete them yourself, if the system lets you):

1. [TabPanels Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719355/tabpanels-rendering)
2. [Linked View "Template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722809/linked-view-template)
3. [Initialize Function, Adding Component to Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726524/initialize-function-adding-component-to-container)
4. [Nested Lists - Tree Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774702/nested-lists-tree-store)
5. [XML/JSON - Save Data on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796925/xml-json-save-data-on-device)
6. [CSS Inclusion - Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800468/css-inclusion-architect)
7. [IndexOf() on Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815218/indexof-on-model)
8. [Singleton - Undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816514/singleton-undefined)
9. [Undefined Breaks Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820688/undefined-breaks-references)
10. [Local Storage with Composite Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837374/local-storage-with-composite-objects)
11. [Nested List - Back button Removable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838576/nested-list-back-button-removable)
12. [onTapHold on a nestedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844881/ontaphold-on-a-nestedlist)
13. [List - Template What do we do with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897780/list-template-what-can-we-do-with-it)
14. [How to retrieve parent of a DataView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899010/how-to-retrieve-parent-of-a-dataview)
15. [Cannot call getAt of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899681/canot-call-methd-getat-of-null-never-ever-calling-getat)
16. [Error when Ext.Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926702/error-when-ext-createmodel-with-parameters)
17. [Local Storage, How safe is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940828/local-storage-how-safe-is-it)

Comment: The third point is kind of stupid. By asking the question I learn that  deletion counted toward ''question banned'' I didnt know before and nothing would ever tell me at all!

Since my existing content is in a small community, it won't get much upvote. IS that it? I'm question banned forever for trying to help...

Comment: @Fawar this concern is addressed in [Notify users when they are approaching the threshold of getting banned...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145456/notify-users-when-they-are-approaching-the-threshold-of-getting-banned-or-when)

Comment: @Fawar: By deleting content you are not helping. The site is all abaout questions that help future visitors and not just you. So keep the question for others with the same problem.

Comment: @Fawar I didn't explain that well, but I'm thinking of "Rubber Duck Programming". Specifically, write your question out, and in the course of writing it out, sometimes you learn what the answer is.  Only submit it if you've written it out, thought about it, worked on it some more, spoken about it to a rubber duck, and still don't know the answer.  It just seems like you're quick to post a question, instead of being sure that you've tried everything before posting.

Comment: @gnat This feature would be good

Thank you George, for the links, I will see what I can do.  Plus i'm working 8hours a day on this single project ( intership) so even when I'm blocked I work all day on it to get the job done.

Comment: If you realize the answer to your question, then rather than deleting the question, post the answer as an answer!  That's pretty useful for others, after all.

Comment: @Joe  sometimes I find the answer and understand it was stupid from me. Exemple, missing a coma in my code.

Comment: Honestly I'd still leave that question and answer it.  You'd be surprised at how useful that can be - perhaps the particular error you get is actually indicative of a missing comma, and someone else searches that error, discovers your answer, and discovers their missing comma!

Comment: @Joe Most of those kinds of questions are just going to be closed as "too localized" because they really aren't useful to others.  Really in cases like that it generally means that you didn't take enough time working on the problem yourself before posting it, particularly when it happens as many times as it has for this user.

Comment: Sure, but I think you might as well leave that to the other users to decide - perhaps in case it actually is useful.  Certainly agree with thinking before posting of course; just if you've already posted, might as well answer it.

Comment: @Servy It happened twice out of 30 questions. Don't make me look like that.

Comment: @Fawar You've deleted 17 of 30 questions, so while they may not all have been a missing comma, they were apparently questions that you didn't spend enough time/effort on before asking.

Comment: @Servy  At the moment they were asked those question were legitimate, but with the experience gained, I see that some of these were quite easy and it was the fact I was not used at all with sencha that made me ask those.

Comment: @Fawar Either the information is readily available and you simply didn't take the time/effort to work on the problem before asking, or it's not, and the question shouldn't have been deleted because it's *not* easily discoverable information.