# Warning before auto-disabling accounts of Users

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

It would be useful to the user to warn them before there account is disabled from posting questions. User doesn't realize that they can be actually be barred from posting questions.

My account was disabled on ServerFault, for reasons I now understand are valid. In my case I came to know the reason **after** SF stopped taking questions from my account. On SO I am a normal contributing member of the community.

Now I tried improving my questions, try to contribute to the community, etc.

I still have a legitimate question for SF, but I'm waiting for my account to reactivate.

If I had been warned of the impending consequences of my misunderstandings I may have avoided all this in the first place is the point.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123026/warn-users-before-their-account-is-suspended

Comment: It's worth noting in this particular case that @codingcrow was Q-banned for deleting lots of their own questions.  This is probably an edge-case in the question-ban algorithm and *may* be worth some kind of automatic notice like `Hey if you keep deleting your questions we're gonna assume something's wrong!`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quality ban warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236800/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364409/282094  
and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86603/282094

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are already ample warning mechanisms in place (comments, downvotes, question closures).

As a new user unfamiliar with Stack Exchange the mechanisms above should be more than sufficient to let someone know that they're doing something wrong and need to spend quality time with the FAQ.  If they persist in misbehaving the automatic (and temporary) ban is a good alternative to leaving it to moderators, who will quickly become annoyed at dealing with yet another mess.

In your case as an experienced user coming from another site we reasonably expect that you are familiar with some of the Stack Exchange idiosyncrasies (like question/answer bans and what triggers them), and that you will avoid behavior that will run afoul of such automated systems.

---

Bottom line, I don't see much value in what you're proposing for Server Fault, and I certainly don't want mods to become responsible for administering such warnings to people as a matter of local site policy.

If you believe there should be some kind of network-wide "warning mechanism" when someone is coming close to being question- or answer-banned from a site you should post that as a feature request on [mSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) as it's a network-wide change.
Coming complete with a description of how such a warning might work / be integrated into existing mechanisms on Stack Exchange sites (supercollider?) would probably help your case.