# Quality ban warning

Tags: support, moderator-tools, users, post-ban, question-quality

How does the hobbling for bad askers work, on sites where the question ban isn't enabled?

In particular, as a moderator, I see repeated entries in a user's history stating

> user posted after seeing a quality ban warning

What does this warning look like? What “quality ban” are they heading towards, and how fast? How long would this ban last?

Comment: The quality ban of "to increase this site's quality, you have been banned." </snark>

Answer (score 30):

It's a [warning that we show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773) to folks who *are near* a quality block, or *would be near* a quality block if they were enabled on the site. As we could (in theory) enable them at any point where we and the moderators of a site deemed them necessary, we warn unconditionally.

While the user isn't actually going to *be* blocked (though they will soon be [rate limited based on the quality of their recent contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits) regardless of blocks being enabled or not), the warning is in fact useful - they need to ask better questions.

The philosophy behind this is essentially the same as for the "consistently low quality questions over time" mod message, and on sites *without* automatic question-bans it should be treated in the same fashion: if someone has been repeatedly warned and continues to contribute poorly, they should be suspended.

Logging this is a rather useful utility, because you (as a moderator, this is not visible to folks without a diamond) can more effectively see how they've been using the site, and that the system *has* in fact attempted to slow them down. Hence, you've got a better overview and more information should you elect to intercede.

**The answer-block warning**:

> Some of your past answers have not been well-received, and you're
>   in danger of being [blocked from
>   answering](/help/answer-bans).
>
> Please pay close attention to the following
>   guidance:
>
> - Please be sure to *answer the question*.
>     Provide details and share your research!
>
> But
>   *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or
>     responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on
>     opinion; back them up with references or personal
>     experience.
>
> To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

**The question-block warning**:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received; if this pattern continues, [we will no longer accept new questions from you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It will _eventually_ go to all sites, however the behavior will be configured to be site-specific - much like private betas, public betas and graduated sites have different reputation scales, with the ability to fine tune as needed.

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual text.

Comment: Does “we will no longer accept new questions from you” link to SO even on other sites? Is this lie shown on sites without a question block?

Comment: @Gilles They're transformed to use the per-site metas, or link to MSE I believe, but I should probably follow up on that and ask someone (as that's how they should be working).

Comment: The links - /help/question-bans and /help/how-to-ask - are relative to the current site, @Gilles. Additionally, the entire warning can be customized on a per-site basis if need-be.

Comment: @TimPost yeah, thanks.  I realized that you said it originally when I reread your question (hence the deleted comment), but the the fine-tuning feature sounds excellent