# I am in Danger of being banned! But Why?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban

I recently got the notification on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) that I am facing the danger of being banned from asking more questions:

[image]

This hit me completely by surprise and so I checked my profile and [my past questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/32442/marc-wellman?tab=questions).

Is the rating of the previous two (!) questions really so heavily weighted that I am in danger of being banned?

Am I missing something??

btw.: This notification only appears on the [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) site and on none of my other SE sites where I am active.

As the warning system is network-wide, rather than specific to a particular site, the question is here rather than on ELU meta.

Comment: What are your newest questions? The early warning system looks at these.

Comment: I have replaced the second screenshot by the question list ordered by date. Could it be that the last two questions cause such a notification??

Comment: @marcwellman: yes, those last two posts were not *well received* and play a role in the warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow)

Comment: ...see also: [Quality ban warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236802/165773)

Comment: While the warning system is network-wide, your specific case is specific to http://english.stackexchange.com/ and should be discussed in its per meta site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't see older deleted posts (IIRC, a link to deleted posts only appears if there are recent deletions), so maybe there are some.

And from what we can see of your questions, one's closed, another's a duplicate, and a third should probably have been closed as a duplicate, as identified in one of the comments on it.

So the warning is true: some of your previous questions have not been well-received.

The system looks to me to be behaving as it should. The system does remove the question-asking privilege for people who ignore the warning, and repeatedly produce low-quality questions. And the system does now give you enough *early* warning to change your behaviour before further questions result in that privilege being removed. That's what's happening now - it's an *early* warning, giving you enough time to react. It's up to you what you do about it.

Comment: I see ... I was just wondering why just two bad-quality questions give me such a warning; especially when I look what some people at StackExchange use to post. But it seems that you are right .. thank you for replying.

Comment: @marcwellman I think the design intent is that this is an **early** warning system: it kicks in early enough when there's still plenty of opportunity for you to do something about it.

Answer (score 7):

You received the warning automatically because of your 2 most-recent questions. Both questions were closed, and one of them was downvoted to -2. It looks like that is enough to give you a reminder to post good, on-topic questions.

It is *just* a warning, and you can ignore it if you feel your questions *on the whole* meet the quality standards.

In other words, see it as someone shouting *Oi, if you keep heading in that direction you'll fall of the cliff into the shark-infested waters! Be careful!* rather than imminent banning.

Comment: yes it seems you are right, all of you are. However, it's a hard warning for just two-bad quality questions... Thank you.

Comment: @marc are you 100% sure you do not have deleted questions in your history? Might even be over year ago, maybe when you was still very new?

Comment: when I click on the link "deleted questions" it tells me "There are no deleted questions".

Comment: @marcwellman that view is limited to posts deleted in the past 60 days though.