# Move the question/answer ban meta to per-site help

Tags: feature-request, meta, new-users, off-topic, help-center

This relates to [People get lost and crash into meta - maybe we need roadblocks for their safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306329/152515) and the issue it's dealing with: people ask off-topic questions on here all the time. I think it's common knowledge that a non-negligible portion have certainly been question banned elsewhere.

In addition to setting up roadblocks, I think something else that would help is simply not sending people here so soon to begin with.

Let's consider the process a relatively new question-banned user goes through:

1. Someone understands how their Stack operates extremely poorly and eventually gets question banned.
2. The first thing they see is a message directing them to [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/152515)
3. Once clicking that link they realise they're on, wow, a brand new Q&A site! An active one with lots of people! With a big ol' Ask Question button in the top right!
4. They can't use that other Q&A site so hey, maybe they can ask their question here!

Since the user understands our Q&A network poorly enough they got question banned in the first place it's also very unlikely they'd recognise step 4 is a bad idea, or they want to do it anyway because they have nothing to lose.

My suggestion: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/152515) should not be a meta post, but instead a page on the per-site help center users are directed to. This reduces the likelihood they'll wind up here, instead of the current approach which puts them on a downhill slope to wind up here almost immediately.

This won't stop *all* the off-topic questions we get but it may at least reduce the quantity and frequency.

Comment: Note to other users: The related questions are not really duplicates. They have been marked as [tag:status-completed] and were about adding a site in the help center. This post is about modifying this site that was created as a result of the related posts.

Comment: I wanted to write that your proposal would disallow community editing, but the post is already locked, so this is a fine idea.

Comment: I assumed SO users who get banned are directed to the identical [SO Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) about what to do when they get banned. Is that not the case?

Comment: I always thought that q-ban users are redirected to the help center already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans. The meta posts merely exist to be (ab)used as dupe target when those users still turn up on meta without showing they have read what was already offered to them..

Comment: Not having been question-banned myself, I'm going by what I've picked up elsewhere--but maybe I've learned wrong. Dx

Comment: Before even considering this, some solid metrics should be employed. In a one-week period, for instance, find out how many unique people have posted a question here and, of those, how many of them are question-banned at one or more child sites. Without that, the premise is just speculative.

Comment: Hasn’t it linked to the help center for a while? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306585/323179.