# Post ban warning not showing up

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-ban

Back in 2014, [a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165261) was added for posters who are on their way to receiving a question ban.  That post includes screenshots of the warning, but the visual styling depicted in the screenshots is noticeably different than the current styling.

Recently, we've had a couple people complain about not seeing these warnings, including one who is [quite adamant that they did not see a warning that looks like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407109/seemingly-got-banned-for-no-reason-without-a-warning#comment839596_407109).

Thus the question: has the warning's appearance changed since 2014?  If so, what does it look like currently?

Comment: I could, of course, go ask a bunch of bad questions on a sockpuppet, but that seems like a terrible idea :-)

Comment: If the only issue is "**another** user claims of no warning" then it's a [duplicate of the question several hours earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407106/3648282), where the same moderator engaged in a similar explanation in the comments; such a claim has [been made a few times recently (there)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-ban). If "the only thing **you** want to know" is "what does it look like?", I'm wondering what would it look like, or how ought it to be presented, so that one could not make such a claim.

Comment: Well, the request is to know what it looks like.  I don't really care whether it's posted by a moderator, a staff member, or a user who's asked too many poorly received questions.  I feel that's fairly clear from the fact that the three sentences ending in question marks (one of which is the title) ask that: "What does the post (question/answer) ban warning look like?", "has the warning's appearance changed since 2014?", and "If so, what does it look like currently?"

Comment: The most important question to SE devs is: *Does it even work?* and if the reaction is *of course* then a screenshot would be awesome.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407109/seemingly-got-banned-for-no-reason-without-a-warning#comment839591_407109

Comment: It seems I was wrong. They've posted multiple questions in the past six months, so it's not that they were already previously banned and it was just reimposed.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - I brought up that up earlier (now deleted comment), however, the user also claims they have never seen the warning (despite the log saying it was shown 8 times).  I think there is merit, just to give everyone a warm and fuzzy, to make sure the warning is still actually working. In the case of this particular user were talking about it probably doesn't matter because they also saw it in 2017, 2020, and 2021 (according to the server logs)

Comment: If the warning remains what's in [the announcement you linked](/a/231118/271271), it would be a good idea to have a feature request to change both notices, or at least the question notice, to something more noticeable. Preferably, this would be a modal dialog which the user needs to acknowledge. It appears the answer notification might be that, or at least a popup, but the question notice appears to be something quite easy to miss, particularly for users who have already demonstrated, by the poor reception of their questions, that they are not paying attention to suggestions from the system.

Comment: FWIW, [I have asked Adam directly on that announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#comment1182894_231118) 7 months ago due to the same claim that a Q-banned user didn't see any warning, but alas, no response.

Comment: It still looks the same. The text is the same, still a notice. Probably some stylistic changes to bring it in line with Stacks. **However**, from what I can tell, the warning is only ever displayed in the v1 ask editor. In the v2 ask editor, there *is* a line that inserts a form variable as to whether the user was shown a warning (which gets set to true and then records a history event later), but there *is not* a block where the message is actually getting inserted for them to view. So it's more of a "should have been shown the warning" variable. I guess someone forgot to put it back in. :/

Comment: So all the users who complained they hadn't been warned about their impending question-ban *really hadn't been warned?* Wow. Any idea how long this has been broken for?

Comment: I'm retagging this as a bug and adding it to the backlog of tasks for the team to look into addressing. Thanks to @animuson for identifying the issue here. :)

Comment: @F1Krazy since January, 16th for sure: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404510/allow-old-poorly-asked-questions-to-eventually-age-away-for-purposes-of-the-que/404517?noredirect=1#comment819702_404517

Comment: @Catija consider also somehow clearing/softening q-bans of users who got these without warnings (it hurts me so friggin' much to propose this but the other way hurts even more because it feels too unfair)

Comment: @gnat While it is unfortunate that the explicit warning was not being displayed, it's not like users received no feedback. The user's posts would have still been substantially downvoted, closed, and deleted, which are the *primary* indicators and feedback wrt. post quality, along with comments for specific issues. *Most* such users *will* have received some warning, due to being blocked from posting for a lesser time during the early stages of the ban. The fact that there are consequences to getting negative feedback is not something that's unusual in the world, in fact I'd expect it's normal.

Comment: The Q&A bans exist to prevent users from continuing to make negative contributions. We should balance any concern of "fairness" to the question/answer banned users (who primarily get banned through their own actions over time not meeting community expectations) with consideration of the additional harm/cost to the community of allowing those users to continue contributing negatively (bans exist because that harm is already significant). Even if the users weren't explicitly warned about the ban, I don't consider it unfair for there to be negative consequences to repeated negative contributions.

Comment: @Makyen well your are words I've been telling myself from the very moment I saw this question posted hinting a chance for a real bug here. Somehow, it didn't help, sorry. "Fairness"... is maybe not the most accurate word to describe what I want. And what I want is to be able to think and say to banned folks, _"You were banned after being warned. System now forces you to spend time learning how to use it correctly because you declined this opportunity when prompted in a softer way. Go learn and stop wasting our time."_ Apparently, this turns into irrelevant noise if there were no warnings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

This was a missed requirement when we built the new question asking form.  The input element that records it was shown was left in but the message was never rendered, hence the confusion.  As a dev on the project this was my fault, so I'm sorry for any problems that came out of this.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know when it was broken, so that moderators can know which users were actually shown the warning based on when the system recorded showing it?

Comment: It's been broken since [March 3rd, 2020 on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network), a little longer on international overflows, and September 2019 or earlier on Stack Overflow since we had an experiment there.  Basically, a long time.  The data is not 100% cut-and-dry through, since the mobile theme was still serving up the warning.

Comment: Something similar seems to have happened [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417162/why-is-my-account-question-banned#comment903368_417162). Is it related to this issue, or is it a different one?